# Can't understand why the my array is mutating in my Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I understand that in React you want to keep your state immutable all the time.

Maybe there are a few flaws in my login of state and immutability. Correct me if I am wrong, but the core of the state's object is managed in the reducers right? Meaning, if I want my `state` of `users` (for example) to be a list... I would want to shape it into an array.

Hence, I set my `inititalState = []`. Here is where I believe I am stumped. I don't know if I am understanding this properly or I am not not thinking.

Previously I was doing,

```
case GET_USERS:
  return [...state, 
    Object.assign({}, action.payload)
  ];
```

But I was advised to change it to `return [...state, ...action.payload];` considering it's not an object or keys I am mutating. Right now I assume, `return [...state, ...action.payload];` is replacing `state`, with `action.payload`, **BUT THAT'S NOT THE CASE AT ALL**.

Every time I try and filter a user... it simply **MUTATES** and **pushes** the user object to `this.props.users` and I am confused about how, because I am trying my best to follow the Redux documentation.

Comment: You mention filtering users but your code shows no `.filter()` can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: For filter, I am simply using a search query. This was just an example, but what I am striving for is something like this. `this.getUsers(searchQuery){ this.props.getUsers(searchQuery).bind(this))}`. Then all I am doing is simply mapping `this.props.users.map(....`

Comment: It will be very difficult to determine the issue you're having without seeing what you've already tried in terms of filtering.  If your `GET_USERS` reducer simply returns `[...state, ...action.payload]`, then it will continue to append the `action.payload` to `state` every time the action is called.  No filtering exists in your code.

Comment: Simple try this: 

case GET_USERS:
  return action.payload;

Comment: You know what this is it. This will work. Thank you mate! Now I just have to figure why it isn't async. For example. If type `M` it does **NOT** filter. When I type `Mo` it gives me the results of `M`. When I type `Mon` it gives me the results of `Mo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `...state` will have your `users` list. During the next call you're just appending the new users into the `state`. Intead, you should be returning the `payload`.

Try the following.

```
case GET_USERS:
  return [...action.payload];
```

Comment: Yeah this did the trick. I must have done something stupid like copy and paste a similar reducer without thinking all the way through. If we want to return a new copy of the updated state every time... then how come things like  `(...state, ...updatedState)` exist? Doesn't that make it mutable?

Comment: You can do `[...state, ...updatedState]`. Check [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=latest&code=const%20a%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20%5B4%2C5%2C6%5D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20%5B...a%2C%20...b%5D%0Aconsole.log(c))